# Beautiful Soup: Data Values Not Matching Headings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and I'm working on a learning project where I'm attempting to scrape some data on College Football Players. The source code for the website looks like this :

```
</thead>
   <tbody>


>    <tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="year_id" ><a
> href="/cfb/years/1957.html">1957</a></th><td class="left "
> data-stat="school_name" csk="San Jose State.1957" ><a
> href="/cfb/schools/san-jose-state/1957.html">San Jose
> State</a></td><td class="left " data-stat="conf_abbr" ><a
> href="/cfb/conferences/independent/1957.html">Ind</a></td><td
> class="center " data-stat="class" ></td><td class="center "
> data-stat="pos" >RB</td><td class="right " data-stat="g" >10</td><td
> class="right " data-stat="rec" >1</td><td class="right "
> data-stat="rec_yds" >6</td><td class="right "
> data-stat="rec_yds_per_rec" >6.0</td><td class="right "
> data-stat="rec_td" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="rush_att"
> >1</td><td class="right " data-stat="rush_yds" >3</td><td class="right " data-stat="rush_yds_per_att" >3.0</td><td class="right "
> data-stat="rush_td" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="scrim_att"
> >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="scrim_yds" >9</td><td class="right " data-stat="scrim_yds_per_att" >4.5</td><td class="right
> " data-stat="scrim_td" >0</td></tr>
```

Here is how far I've gotten with my code :

```
headers = [item["data-stat"] for item in soup.find_all(attrs={"data-stat" : True})]
cellStrings = [cell.find(text = True) for cell in soup.findAll('td')]
print headers, cellStrings
```

This prints out the following:

```
[u'', u'header_receiving', u'header_rushing', u'header_scrimmage', u'year_id', u'school_name', u'conf_abbr', u'class', u'pos', u'g', u'rec', u'rec_yds', u'rec_yds_per_rec', u'rec_td', u'rush_att', u'rush_yds', u'rush_yds_per_att', u'rush_td', u'scrim_att', u'scrim_yds', u'scrim_yds_per_att', u'scrim_td', u'year_id', u'school_name', u'conf_abbr', u'class', u'pos', u'g', u'rec', u'rec_yds', u'rec_yds_per_rec', u'rec_td', u'rush_att', u'rush_yds', u'rush_yds_per_att', u'rush_td', u'scrim_att', u'scrim_yds', u'scrim_yds_per_att', u'scrim_td', u'year_id', u'school_name', u'conf_abbr', u'class', u'pos', u'g', u'rec', u'rec_yds', u'rec_yds_per_rec', u'rec_td', u'rush_att', u'rush_yds', u'rush_yds_per_att', u'rush_td', u'scrim_att', u'scrim_yds', u'scrim_yds_per_att', u'scrim_td'] [u'San Jose State', u'Ind', None, u'RB', u'10', u'1', u'6', u'6.0', u'0', u'1', u'3', u'3.0', u'0', u'2', u'9', u'4.5', u'0', u'San Jose State', None, None, None, None, u'1', u'6', u'6.0', u'0', u'1', u'3', u'3.0', u'0', u'2', u'9', u'4.5', u'0']
```

The problem is some of the headings appear earlier in the source code, so the two lists, data and the headings, do not match.

My question is how can I pull the 'data-stat' along with it's associated value instead of pulling them separately? Ideally, I would pull this as a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm getting you correctly, you want a dictionary consisting of `{'data-stat-value': 'value of td'}`; you can do something like this:

```
data_stats = {e['data-stat']: e.get_text().strip()
              for e in html.find_all(attrs={'data-stat': True})}
```

this way it will surely pull the text associated with that `data-stat` tag.